# Manually specify dns server in android

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to manually specify DNS server address before an http request.

Can't find anything helpful about this. Any advice?

Comment: Programmatically, It is not a setting that you would set "per request".

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. i will give it a try

Answer (score -1):

If you are using an emulator, it inherits the DNS properties of your machine/laptop that it is connected to.

Hence change the DNS in your laptop from which the emulator launches and it uses the same settings

Comment: Question asked programmatically though Java.

Comment: note the word manually in the question. its not specified programatically in question title nor body @cricket_007

Comment: Manually before an HTTPRequest? Question was tagged with Java. This is a programming site. It was certainly implied.